# MYSQL join one table to another single tables multiple times best way

Tags: mysql

Ok I have Two Tables

One is **business**

```
id
name
telephone
primary_category
secondary_category
tertiary_category
```

Another table is **category**

```
id
name
parent_id
```

Now a business must have a primary/ secondary and optional tertiary category in this instance is this the only way to to this

```
SELECT * FROM business b
INNER JOIN business_category bc_1 ON b.primary_category = bc.id
INNER JOIN business_category bc_2 ON b.secondary_category = bc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN business_category bc_3 ON b.tertiary_category = bc.id
```

Seem quite long for all i want is the name for each category in the business table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the way you are doing right now is already efficient. You have many alternatives such as creating subqueries on it but its less efficient than the one you have created.

If you have properly defined indexes on all tables then it's good to go. More specifically on these columns:

```
primary_category
secondary_category
tertiary_category
```

because these are foreign keys from **category** table.

Comment: does this not work SELECT * FROM business b
INNER JOIN business_category bc ON b.primary_category = bc.id AND b.secondary_category = bc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN business_category bc_3 ON b.tertiary_category = bc_3.id

Comment: @MatthewChambers no, it's very very different from `business b
INNER JOIN business_category bc_1 ON b.primary_category = bc.id
INNER JOIN business_category bc_2 ON b.secondary_category = bc.id` if you do that you will have incorrect results. you cannot display the name of the category for `secondary_category` column.

Comment: ok thanks john and my structure is ok too- dont need a table in between- the is perfectly acceptable practice?

Comment: it may be. don't make things complicated. :D

Comment: i think as it is one to one should not have a table in between- i will keep with initial question i think is best- table in between would mean it was optional whereas it is mandatory